# Getting xml response to html

Tags: c#, javascript, html, xml

This is not working. I have created a web-service in which after invoking I get output: 
`"<"string>user-hp/user</string">""`

So I want to get the output as `"user-hp/user"` on a `html page` and I have used this code but it shows nothing but a blank page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title></title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

      var Soap_a = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body><HelloWorld xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"></Helloworld></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("GET", "user.asmx", false);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=utf-8");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", Soap_a.length.toString());
      xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "\"http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld\"");
      xhr.send(Soap_a);
      var xmlDoc = xhr.responseXML;
      var resultNodee = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("string");
      var result = resultNodee[0].childNodes[0].data;
      document.getElementById("string").innerHTML = result;

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="string"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the dev console show? How does the request look?

Comment: this is a html page and after running it in a browser it shows the blank page

Comment: Yes, you already told that and that is not enough to diagnose

Comment: rene mam help me to tell you about my problem precisely by explaning what does this request look means..??

Comment: If you hit F12 (in Chrome or IE) the dev console shows. When you load your page you can see which requests are send amd what the response is. And in the console you can see if there any errors. And you can put a breakpoint on the first line of your javascript and then step through your code...

Answer (score 0):

The reason here is that the script is executing before the entire HTML DOM is constructed. Due to which the JavaScript engine is unable to locate `<div id="string">`.

If you are sure that your script should run perfectly fine then move the `<script>` tag to the end, just before the close of `</body>`, something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="string"></div>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

      var Soap_a = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body><HelloWorld xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"></Helloworld></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("GET", "user.asmx", false);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=utf-8");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", Soap_a.length.toString());
      xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "\"http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld\"");
      xhr.send(Soap_a);
      var xmlDoc = xhr.responseXML;
      var resultNodee = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("string");
      var result = resultNodee[0].childNodes[0].data;
      document.getElementById("string").innerHTML = result;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This will ensure that all the `div` and other tags are created before the script is executed.

> Please use this as a starting point and not as a copy-paste solution.

Comment: still it is not working and shows the blank page but when i tried with "POST" and "var resultNodee = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("*");" then it shows output : undefined

Comment: IMO you don't need POST. GET should be fine. Debug your script using the browser script debugger